problema al obtener token para mensajes push web con firebase
soy nuevo en esto, tengo un  problema cuando intento obtener el token del usuario.
El getToken me da el error dice que no es una función pero no logro encontrar lo que esta mal, si alguien me puede colaborar por favor, aquí les dejo el codigo.
e intentado buscar algun problema similar a ver pero no consigo.


  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/11.0.1/firebase-app.js";

  import { 
  getMessaging, 
  onMessage, 
  getToken, 
} from  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/11.0.1/firebase-messaging.js" ; 


// Add Firebase products that you want to use


  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "28",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };

  // Initialize Firebase


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = getMessaging()


messaging.getToken({vapidKey: "BOboa-OiHFV0r7JneyHX"})
messaging.onMessage((payload) =>{

const messagesElement = document.querySelector('.message')
const dataHeaderElement = document.createElement('H5')
const dataElement = document.createElement('pre')
dataElement.style = "overflow-x hidden;"
dataHeaderElement.textContent = "Message Recived:"
dataElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2)
messagesElement.appendChild(dataHeaderElement)
messagesElement.appendChild(dataHeader)
})



